# How to avoid bcrypt-node adding slashes to the URL string hash?

Tags: node.js, encryption, bcrypt

I'm using [brypt-nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs) to generate a hash, but sometimes it adds slashes into the string it generates, like the one below, which poses difficulties for me when I try to send it over URL.

```
$12$G/KJOwTBLjGwcnAGaTlJMnAnkXa6/M1jt8FppD
```

Is there a setting in bcrypt that would generate hashes without the slash or should I just remove them manually or replace with some unlikely pattern (e.g. `slashslash`) to be able to recover its occurrence, should it arise?

```
$12$GslashslashKJOwTBLjGwcnAGaTlJMnAnkXa6slashslashM1jt8FppD
```

Thank you for letting me know your ideas!

Comment: That's what it's *supposed* to do, `algo/hash/salt`. Why are you trying to put that in a URL?

Comment: You should URL encode it using `encodeURI()`, but I'm also wondering about putting such a thing in a URL.

Comment: @JamesKPolk this didn't help. for now i settled with manually replacing all the occurrences of hash with an unlikely pattern and then re-replacing it.

Answer (score 3):

**you can replace the / with another string eg "slash"**

This is how you would handle your hash after receiving it:

```
 hash.replace(/\//g, "slash");
```

To compare you must convert back the "slash" to /

```
.compare(user.id, req.params.secretToken.replace(/slash/g, "/"))
```

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; You cannot.

`bcrypt` follows the [modular crypt format](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/practical-unix-and/0596003234/ch04s03.html). Changing it to use something other than a slash will make hashes incompatible with other implementations. bcrypt hashes are base64 encoded, which *includes / in its charset*.

Alternatively, you can do a manual transformation over the generated hash, or build your own implementation with the base_64 encoding that substitutes / with something else.

Answer (score 1):

While @AdrianJohn suggested the way to replace the slash character in the hashed password, it seems to be the way to do. However, it's not an efficient solution. Because, when you replace that forward slash, chances are the password will definitely be different when it comes to comparing it to the plain one with the `bcrypt.compare` method.

Here is the way to do: you have to re-run the `bcrypt.hash` method until the library will offer you a URL-safe password (without the slash).

I was looking for the solution out there... no answer. Behold what I've made on my own and it works like disco!

```
handlePasswordHashing = (plainPassword, salt) => {
    let hashed = bcrypt.hashSync(plainPassword, salt)

    if (hashed.includes("/")) {
       hashed = this.handlePasswordHashing(plainPassword, salt)
    }

    return hashed
}
```

Note: Re-running the hash many times doesn't change the algorithm. Even though the password is always different once hashed, it's always the same as its plain one.

Comment: Definitely agree with this suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `/` and `+` symbols with `&` or literally any other unused url-safe symbol

```
bcrypt = "$2a$04$Xdbla3daq84.TJZ2deXSBOZ3humTScPlgkMZoUH6gNC0NoZiqblVa";
urlsafe = str_replace(bcrypt, {"/", ";"}, {"+", "*"});
```